# Question on convergence of a sequence of functions uniformly on compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to understand this argument on convergence of a sequence
of functions from a research paper (the function is random but we can make the following argument for each sample path).

Consider a sequence of functions $f^{r}(t):[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ such that for each $r$, $f^{r}(t)$  is nondecreasing in $t$,
$$
f^{r}(s)-f^{r}(t)\leq(s-t),\quad t\leq s,
$$
and $f^{r}(t)\leq t$. Then it is stated that since the above holds
we can conclude that for each sequence there exists a subsequence
say $\{r_{j}\}$ such that 
$$
f^{r_{j}}(t)\rightarrow f(t),\quad \mbox{ u.o.c. as } \quad j\rightarrow\infty,
$$
for some function $f(t)$, where *u.o.c.* stands for uniformly on
compact sets.

Questions: (1) Does the above follow using the Arzelà - Ascoli
theorem and the fact that $f^{r}$ is Lipschitz and bounded on any
compact set $[0,T]$?

(2) Given that any sequence has a convergent subsequence can we then
conclude that $f^{r}(t)\rightarrow f(t)$ $u.o.c.$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$?

Thanks for elaborating!

Comment: Looks to me like you left off some absolute value signs. Also, what is the domain of these functions?

Comment: Right. I forgot to mention that the functions are nondecreasing. I'll add the domain too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're set up to use Arzela-Ascoli. You have uniform boundedness on each $[0,T]$ and global equicontinuity. So A-A gives a subsequence that converges uniformly on $[0,1],$ then a subsequence of that which converges uniformly on $[0,2],$ etc. Then diagonalize to obtain a final subsequence that CUOCS.

The answer to 2. is no. Example: $0,t, 0, t, 0, t, \dots.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure that I understand the answer to 2 (and the example). Can't I conclude that for sufficiently large $r$, $f^{r}(t)$ is close to $f(t)$ uniformly on any compact set given that any sequence has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: $0,t,0,t,\dots $ at $t=1$ is the sequence $0,1,0,1,\dots $ which fails to converge.

Comment: I see. How about any strictly increasing sequence $\{r\}$? Then can we conclude from (1) that we have $f^{r}(t)\rightarrow f(t)$?

Comment: You mean for each $t$ the sequence $f^r(t)$ is increasing?

Comment: Ok, the way I'm thinking about this is that we have a sequence of
functions $\{f^{r}(t);r=1,2,3,...\}$. The first result says that
there exists a convergent subsequence $\{f^{r_{j}}(t);j=1,2,3,...\}$.
Then doesn't this mean, for the original sequence, that as long as
we're far along this seuqnce of functions or $r$ is sufficiently
large then $f^{r}$ is uniformly close to $f$?

Comment: No, again go back to $0,t,0,t,…$ That sequence is $0,1,0,…$
 at $1.$ There is no way the last sequence far enough along is going to converge.